# Undo Framework Design (Revert the changes in the collection)

Tags: c#, framework

Requirement is to monitor the changes in a `List<T>`, possible changes are `Add / Remove / Update`, which are registered in an Audit log, which I do in the code underneath using a `Dictionary`. Now user can take an action to revert each of the operations, using an integrated `Action` delegate. Each operation runs its respective Revert operation. Please note here undo is not about notification, like `ObservableCollection<T>` but removal at the later time based on user discretion.
Following is my design, please suggest, what shall be done to further improvise.

---

```
public class ActionWrapper<T>
{
    public int Index {get;set;}
    public T OriginalValue {get;set;}
    public T NewValue {get;set;}
    public Action<int,T> Action {get;set;}  
}

public class ChangeList<T> : List<T> 
                             where T:class,IEquatable<T>
{
    public Dictionary<T,ActionWrapper<T>> ActionMap {get;set;}

    public ChangeList()
    {
        ActionMap = new Dictionary<T,ActionWrapper<T>>();
    }

    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        base.Add(item); 

        var actionWrapper = new ActionWrapper<T>
        {
            Action = new Action<int,T>(RevertAdd),
            Index = this.FindIndex(x => x.Equals(item)),
            NewValue = item,
            OriginalValue = null
        };

        ActionMap[actionWrapper.NewValue] = actionWrapper;
    }

    public new void Remove(T item)
    {   
        var actionWrapper = new ActionWrapper<T>
        {
            Action = new Action<int, T>(RevertRemove),
            Index = this.FindIndex(x => x.Equals(item)),
            NewValue = null,
            OriginalValue = item
        };

        if(actionWrapper.Index < 0)
           return;

        base.Remove(actionWrapper.OriginalValue);

        ActionMap[actionWrapper.OriginalValue] = actionWrapper;
    }

    public void Update(T actualValue,T newValue)
    {
        var actionWrapper = new ActionWrapper<T>
        {
            Action = new Action<int, T>(RevertUpdate),
            Index = this.FindIndex(x => x.Equals(actualValue)),
            NewValue = newValue,
            OriginalValue = actualValue
        };

        if (actionWrapper.Index < 0)
            return;

        base[actionWrapper.Index] = newValue;

        ActionMap[actionWrapper.NewValue] = actionWrapper;
    }

    public void RevertAdd(int index, T actual)
    {
        base.Remove(actual);    
    }

    public void RevertRemove(int index,T actual)
    {
        base.Add(actual);
    }

    public void RevertUpdate(int index,T actual)
    {
        base[index] = actual;
    }
}
```

### Use Case

```
void Main()
{
    var changeList = new ChangeList<string>();
    changeList.Add("Person1");
    changeList.Add("Person2");
    changeList.Add("Person3");
    changeList.Add("Person4");
    changeList.Add("Person5");
    changeList.Add("Person6");
    changeList.Add("Person7");
    changeList.Dump(); // Print statement

    var actionMapUpdateAdd = changeList.ActionMap["Person5"];
    actionMapUpdateAdd.Action(actionMapUpdateAdd.Index, actionMapUpdateAdd.NewValue);
    changeList.Dump(); // Print statement

    changeList.Update("Person7","Person77");
    changeList.Dump(); // Print statement

    var actionMapUpdate = changeList.ActionMap["Person77"];
    actionMapUpdate.Action(actionMapUpdate.Index,actionMapUpdate.OriginalValue);     
    changeList.Dump(); // Print statement

    changeList.Remove("Person6");
    changeList.Dump(); // Print statement

    var actionMapRemove = changeList.ActionMap["Person6"];
    actionMapRemove.Action(actionMapRemove.Index, actionMapRemove.OriginalValue);
    changeList.Dump(); // Print statement
}
```

Comment: As a small info, given the `ActionMap` as a public property with a public setter is just asking for problems, for that having a method recovering the `ActionWrapper` should greatly reduce the risk there of user manipulation

Comment: Thanks @Icepickle, please check latest Edit 1, it does take care of points you have raised

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers): _**Do not add an improved version of the code** after receiving an answer. Including revised versions of the code makes the question confusing, especially if someone later reviews the newer code._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Edge cases

This fails to handle several edge-cases:

- Undoing a remove action multiple times results in that item being added back multiple times.
- Undoing an update action after other items have been inserted at a lower index causes the wrong items to be replaced.
- Lists can contain duplicate items, but only the last operation for each distinct item is remembered.
- Updating an item leaves the add-operation for the original item, but attempting to undo that add-operation fails unless the update action has first been undone.

As the last point demonstrates, you can't just undo an action without undoing all actions that followed it first. If you do want to support something like that, you'll have to clearly define the requirements and figure out what the desired behavior is for a variety of edge-cases. You'll also want to make this information available to those that will use this code (documentation, see below).

#### Implementation notes

- Hiding methods with `new` is rarely a good idea: `(changeList as IList<string>).Add("untracked item");` probably does not do what you want it to do. In this case, don't inherit from `List<T>`: implement the necessary interfaces manually, and use an internal `List<T>` for the actual storage.
- `List<T>` (and `IList<T>`) provides some other methods (`Insert`, `[int index]` and `Clear`) that are not being 'intercepted', resulting in untracked changes.
- Undoing an action is complicated. Why should the caller need to know whether to use `NewValue` or `OriginalValue`? That makes it difficult to use correctly. Why does the caller need to pass in any arguments at all? Why use a wrapper class if you can just create a closure with all the necessary state?
- Try to use clear, descriptive names. `UndoableAction` and `Undo` are much clearer than `ActionWrapper` and `Action`, and `Replace` is a more accurate description of what the `Update` method does.
- Those `RevertAdd/Remove/Update` methods don't seem to be intended for public use, so don't make them public. They only clutter the interface of your class.
- Those `ActionWrapper` properties should probably not be public either, but if they have to be, then at least make them read-only. You don't want other code to be able to mess with the internals of your change-tracking/undo system. The same goes for that `ActionMap` property: it should only be exposed as a get-only `IReadOnlyDictionary`.
- Documentation is entirely absent. That makes it even more difficult to tell how this class is meant to be used (or even what its exact purpose is), and various details such as `Remove` only removing the first matching item are left to the caller to figure out. It also makes it difficult for others to distinguish between intended and incorrect behavior.

#### Alternative design

I'd go for a different design, one that doesn't expose internal details, doesn't allow for out-of-order undoing (which means less edge-cases), and that provides a simple interface that's easy to use correctly (note how it's not possible to undo the same action multiple times):

```
public class ChangeTrackingList<T> // implements IList<T> and/or other interfaces
{
    private List<T> _items = new List<T>();
    private Stack<Action> _undoActions = new Stack<Action>();

    public bool UndoLastAction()
    {
        if (!_undoActions.Any())
            return false;

        var undoLastAction = _undoActions.Pop();
        undoLastAction();
        return true;
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _items.Add(item);

        // Ensure that this item gets removed, and not an identical earlier occurrence:
        var index = _items.Count - 1;
        _undoActions.Push(() => _items.RemoveAt(index));
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the brilliant set of design suggestions. Mine approach was first attempt and casual. I need to incorporate your suggestions, though the only difference that I have is user has an ability to decide to revert from an intermediary point, which means, that all actions are not undone but part actions are undone. There need to be a mechanism to define it , undo in part and commit the rest

Comment: Also there's a complete undo audit log, which shares the undo actions across various, `ChangeTrackingList<T>`, which needs to be sequentially undone, this would mean a `Stack<Action>` needs to be shared, in any case that's not type dependent even in your code

Comment: So if a user performs actions A, B and C, they should be able to undo B without having to undo C? That's going to be a lot more complicated. And if there are multiple lists (and probably more complex data structures and dependencies) then I think it's better to do change-tracking at a higher level.

Comment: Please check the modified design under Edit1, based on suggestions provided along with the use cases. There's a misunderstanding, if B is removed then C shall also be removed, all post changes shall be removed. However with new design it will be easier to even obtain what you have suggested, since a collection snapshot is taken at point in time (local), which can be shifted to global and intermediary changes can also be removed, post ensuring that its not already done as part of other changes

Comment: Your edit has been rolled back: if you want the updated code to be reviewed you can create a new question instead. Either way, I did take a look at it, and although it's an improvement in some areas, it still contains some major problems: bad use of `static`, not all methods being undoable, still publicly exposing state that should be kept private, interface still being too complex to use, still a lack of useful documentation, etc.

Comment: I also think it's a good idea to provide more concrete context. Can the objects in these lists be modified? Do those changes need to be undoable as well? Are objects in different lists related to each other? You may need an undo system that works at a higher level than just list modifications...

Comment: Reason for using static is different collection types create reversible action, which are sequential operation, so `A-B-C-D` all actions have to happen sequentially but they will happen in different collections, which created them. Undo is only required for few operations, where its added, not for everything by use case. Not sure of any other interface beside `IList<T>` which can offer all the functionality of the `List<T>` and customize it

Comment: Will create a separate question for the new version of the Undo Framework

Comment: You don't need to make things static to share them between objects - just pass a reference to your shared change-tracker to all your change-lists (via their constructor). And for those audit objects, a static ID means that all of them will have the same ID - that's clearly a bug. And you might say, I don't need `Insert` to be undoable (which is strange, because it's an `Add` operation), but that breaks undoing of other operations...